Issues Integrating AppLovin with AdMob Mediation in Android App
I'm currently working on integrating AppLovin into my Android application alongside AdMob for ad mediation. While AdMob ads are functioning correctly on their own, adding AppLovin has introduced persistent Gradle errors related to dependency resolution.
Here's what l've done so far:
• Contigured Mediation in AdMob Console: • Added AppLovin as a mediation network. • Followed the setup instructions provided by both AdMob and AppLovin.
The problem is that I don't know what to include in my application's code; this is my first time adding mediation. AdMob ads work perfectly for me, but AppLovin ads are not showing. I would also like to add meta.
What should I include? Or is there a simple tutorial I can follow to implement it for the first time? Thank you.
I have tried adding the dependency to Gradle and configuring the app in AppLovin, as well as setting up AppLovin in AdMob mediation.
